# Any way to show facebook customer Chat Plugin only for visitor having facebook session

Tags: facebook, facebook-customer-chat

I'm thinking in using "facebook customer Chat" as an alternative live chat support in my website, is it available to show it only if the user have a facebook session, mean already logged in, and if not I'm planning to show another live support plugins.
any way to do this?

Comment: I doubt there is a way to check if someone is already logged into facebook, that could be used as a targeting tool for phishing. What I would do, instead, is have a single "live support" button, which opens a modal that contains a button to use Facebook customer chat, or the other live support option which the user can then choose which one they want.

Comment: Check the login status maybe? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/